# Docker + Nginx: Getting proxy_pass to work

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, nginx-location

I'm having a problem trying to get Nginx to proxy a path to another server that is also running in Docker.

To illustrate, I'm using Nexus server as an example.

This is my first attempt...

`docker-compose.yml`:-

```
version: '2'
services:
  nexus:
    image: "sonatype/nexus3"
    ports:
     - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
     - ./nexus:/nexus-data

  nginx:
    image: "nginx"
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    volumes:
    - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
```

`nginx.conf`:-

```
worker_processes 4;
events { worker_connections 1024; }
http {
        server {
              listen 80;

              location /nexus/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
              }
        }
}
```

When I hit `http://localhost/nexus/`, I get 502 Bad Gateway with the following log:-

```
nginx_1  | 2017/05/29 02:20:50 [error] 7#7: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /nexus/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:8081/", host: "localhost"
nginx_1  | 2017/05/29 02:20:50 [error] 7#7: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /nexus/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "localhost"
nginx_1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [29/May/2017:02:20:50 +0000] "GET /nexus/ HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
```

In my second attempt...,

`docker-compose.yml` -  I added `links` to Nginx configuration:-

```
version: '2'
services:
  nexus:
    image: "sonatype/nexus3"
    ports:
     - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
     - ./nexus:/nexus-data

  nginx:
    image: "nginx"
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    volumes:
    - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    links:
    - nexus:nexus
```

`nginx.conf`... Instead of using `http://localhost:8081/`, I use `http://nexus:8081/`:-

```
worker_processes 4;
events { worker_connections 1024; }
http {
        server {
              listen 80;

              location /nexus/ {
                proxy_pass http://nexus:8081/;
              }
        }
}
```

Now, when I hit `http://localhost/nexus/`, it gets proxied properly but the web content is partially rendered. When inspecting the HTML source code of that page, the javascript, stylesheet and image links are pointing to `http://nexus:8081/[path]`... hence, 404.

What should I change to get this to work properly?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following additional options are what I have used

```
http {
    server {
          listen 80;

          location /{
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
            server_name_in_redirect on;
            proxy_pass      http://nexus:8081;

          }

          location /nexus/ {
            proxy_pass          http://nexus:8081/;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
            server_name_in_redirect on;
          }
    }
```

}

My solution is to include the redirect for the '/' path in the nginx config. The Nexus app will be making requests to '/' for it resources which will not work.

However, this is not ideal and will not work with an Nginx configuration serving multiple apps.

The [docs](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/install.html#_example_reverse_proxy_virtual_host_at_custom_context_path)
cover this configuration and indicate that you need to configure Nexus to serve on [`/nexus`](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/install.html#config-context-path). This would enable you to configure Nginx as follows (from docs) minus the hack above.

```
location /nexus {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/nexus;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

I would recommend using that configuration.

Comment: It doesn't work for me... `http://localhost/nexus` gets redirect to `http://nexus`, and I get 404 on that page.

Comment: That will happens since you do not have the trailing '/' which is needed for the location directive to match. That by itself will not solve the problem. I am updating the answer with a solution.

Comment: Configuring Nexus to have a custom context path `/nexus` does the trick for me. Then, I configure proxy_pass to point to `http://nexus:8081/nexus/`. Thank you very much for your help.